# How do I catch error and success for stripe transfer?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to initiate a transfer, but I need to catch the error if there is one and if the transfer was successful I need to perform another method. How do I catch the success/error?

```
stripe.transfers.create({
    amount: payoutAmount*100,
    currency: "usd",
    destination: "default_for_currency",
    method: "instant"
},{stripe_account: String(accountId)}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node.js Stripe library is asynchronous, so you either need to include a callback with [that API call](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_transfer) or return it into a `var` and handle it with [promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html).

Using callbacks, it would be something like this:

```
stripe.transfers.create({
    amount: payoutAmount*100,
    currency: "usd",
    destination: "default_for_currency",
    method: "instant"
}, {stripe_account: String(accountId)}, function(error, transfer) {
    if (error) {
        // Transfer failed, so do something with the error:
        return doSomethingWithError(error);
    }

    // Transfer succeeded, so do something with the Transfer:
    doSomethingWithTransfer(transfer);
});
```